# For which $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ is $x^{5}-ax-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Define $f(x)=x^5-ax-1.$ By the rational root test, we know that possible roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ are $1$ and $-1$, which are also in $\mathbb{Z}$. $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=0$ imply $a=0$ and $a=2$ respectively. So, $f$ is not irreducible if $a\in \{ 1,-1\}$. Omitting these values, we can say that if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for $g,h \in \mathbb{Z} [x]$ then $\deg(g)\neq 1\neq \deg(h)$.

If we assume $\deg(g)=3, \deg(h)=2$, then we can obtain a system of equations via coefficients from both sides of the equation $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, which probably can be solved by elementary arguments that I don't really want to spend the time doing.

For context, I am studying for my graduate level qualifying exam, so I am familiar with basic Galois theory. I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this using more general theory because I'd like to be able to solve this problem quickly in an exam scenario.

Comment: I think $x^5-x-1$ is irreducible, but $x^5+x-1$ is not  irreducible of course.

Comment: *Hint:* Use [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) That will cover all the cases $|a| \geq 2$.

Comment: @Krish How would Eisenstein apply? The constant coefficient is $1$.